# Standard SQL Radians Function

Tags: google-bigquery

Switching from legacy to standard, is there a standard function to convert values into radian, similar to legacy?

Typically, I would use radian() within legacy SQL, but that function doesn't exist within standard.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION RADIANS(x FLOAT64) AS (
  ACOS(-1) * x / 180
);

SELECT RADIANS(37);  -- returns 0.6457718232379019
```

Answer (score 1):

As a shared UDF you can use right now, `fhoffa.x.radians()`:

```
SELECT fhoffa.x.radians(180)

3.141592653589793
```

How-to for persistent UDFs:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83